# Efficient way to crossreference multiple columns with list of strings with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, vectorization

I need to search a dataframe text column for either country names or capital names, then save the hits in a new column. My current solution is working but takes a very long time. I'm wondering if it's possible to make this more effective, ideally in a vectorised fashion.

The list of countries and capitals is stored in the separate `countries` dataframe.

My main dataframe `df`:

```
    date             text
0   2016-01-01       Bla bla bla bla
1   2016-01-01       Blu blu Nigeria
2   2016-01-01       Hey ho Norway
3   2016-01-01       This is text Paris
4   2016-01-01       Lorem lorem ipsum
```

The `countries` dataframe:

```
    name             capital
0   France           Paris
1   Germany          Berlin
2   Norway           Oslo
3   China            Beijing
```

My current solution:

```
def extract_countries(row):
    matches = []
    for country, adj in countries[['name', 'capital']].values:
        if any([country in row.text, adj in row.text]):
            matches.append(country)
    return ', '.join(matches)

df['countries'] = df.apply(extract_countries, axis=1)
```

Desired outcome:

```
    date             text                      countries
0   2016-01-01       Bla bla bla bla           NaN
1   2016-01-01       Blu blu Nigeria           Nigeria
2   2016-01-01       Hey ho Norway             Norway
3   2016-01-01       This is text Paris        France
4   2016-01-01       Lorem lorem ipsum         NaN
5   2016-01-01       Germany attacked Benin    Germany, Benin
```

Comment: Please add some data along with your desired outcome.

Comment: Added more context, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way. Note `NaN` ("Not a Number") is not applicable for string columns, so I have left empty strings where no match is found.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([['2016-01-01', 'Bla bla bla bla'], ['2016-01-01', 'Blu blu Nigeria'],
                   ['2016-01-01', 'Hey ho Norway'], ['2016-01-01', 'This is text Paris'],
                   ['2016-01-01', 'Lorem lorem ipsum']], columns=['date', 'text'])

countries = pd.DataFrame([['France', 'Paris'], ['Germany', 'Berlin'], ['Norway', 'Oslo'],
                          ['China', 'Beijing']], columns=['name', 'capital'])

ctry_set = set(countries.name)
cap_set = set(countries.capital)

df['countries'] = df['text'].apply(lambda x: ', '.join(i for i in ctry_set if i in x))
df['capitals'] = df['text'].apply(lambda x: ', '.join(i for i in cap_set if i in x))

#          date                text countries capitals
# 0  2016-01-01     Bla bla bla bla                   
# 1  2016-01-01     Blu blu Nigeria                   
# 2  2016-01-01       Hey ho Norway    Norway         
# 3  2016-01-01  This is text Paris              Paris
# 4  2016-01-01   Lorem lorem ipsum
```

Comment: Works well! Just had to create a mapping from capitals to countries in the end and combine the `countries` and `capitals` columns.